# Where are added data in database

Tags: postgresql, graphite

I have installed graphite with PostgreSql db (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-graphite-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)

Everything is great and I put some data in it. My question is, can I manage data in Postgres db? I have looked for tables with data in db, but I cant find them. Where are they? I just found only these tables.

- table account_profile
- table account_variable
- table account_view
- ...
- table django_content_type
- table tagging_tag
- table tagging_taggedi

Where are sent data exactly stored? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, Graphite is using the components called 'whisper' and 'Carbon' to store the data. The actual data are stored in this database component.

PostgreSQL is used for metadata by the Django-based web-frontend.